# How to autofill a TextBox that is located on WebForm2 by clicking a button on the main WebForm

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am making an asp.net website and I have a button on the main WebForm that it is hyperlinked with WebForm2.
The WebForm2 that opens is a typical contact form that contains some text boxes, drop down lists and a button that sends an e-mail with the information that I entered.
But because I am making an e-commerce website, depending on which button(on which product) is clicked on the main WebForm, I need to autofill the TextBox that contains the "Product Name" on the WebForm2.
Firstly, I had a JavaScript modal that was opened when the button was clicked, and I made independent forms with different value on the TextBox depending on the Product Name, but I could not figure out how to make the modal functional to send an e-mail, simply the information that was entered could not be proceed an the e-mail that I get was only the mail_message text (ex. Name: , Surname: and Telephone Number: were blank) but not the text that was filled in the form.

**So my question is, how to make the button autofill the TextBox on the WebForm2 that contains the Product Name?**

In case it matters, on the WebForm2 the code that sends me an e-mail is:

```
protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var from = "email";
            var to = "secondemail";
            const string Password = "password";
            string mail_subject = txt_subject.Text.ToString();
            string mail_message = "Your Name: " + txt_name.Text + "\n";
            mail_message += "Your Surname: " + txt_surname.Text + "\n";
            mail_message += "Your telephone number: " + txt_phone.Text + "\n";
            mail_message += "Your address: " + txt_address.Text + "\n";
            mail_message += "Your e-mail: " + txt_email.Text + "\n";
            mail_message += "The product name: " + txt_product.Text + "\n";
            mail_message += "Payment method: " + dropdownlist.SelectedValue + "\n";

            var smtp = new SmtpClient();
            {
                smtp.Host = "smtp@mail";
                smtp.Port = port;
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(from, Password);
                smtp.Timeout = 20000;
            }

            smtp.Send(from, to, mail_subject, mail_message);

            confirm.Text = "Thank you for your order, our team will deliver the product you ordered at your home address as soon as possible.";

            txt_subject.Text = "";
            txt_name.Text = "";
            txt_surname.Text = "";
            txt_phone.Text = "";
            txt_address.Text = "";
            txt_email.Text = "";
            txt_subject.Text = "";
            txt_product.Text = "";
            dropdownlist.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            confirm.Text = "The order can't be proceed at the moment, please try again later.";
            confirm.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
```

**Cheers, grateful for any help.**

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would on web form 1 simply NOT use a hyper link, and use a button.

When you click that button, you set/get/grab the value you want, save it say in session() and then in the web form 2, you can grab that value.

So here is web form 1:

Say a grid to select somthing:

```
        <br />
        <h2>Please select Hotel</h2>

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" SortExpression="HotelName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Province" HeaderText="Province" />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select Hotel">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="cmdSEL" runat="server" Text="Pick me"
                            RowID = '<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' 
                            onclick="cmdSEL_Click"
                            />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

So it looks like this:

[image]

The code is not much, but we PASS the row selected - that way this is less code, less world poverty, and it not really much code at all.

So the code for above is this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack == false)
        LoadGrid();
}

public void LoadGrid()
{
    string strSQL 
= "SELECT ID, HotelName, City, Province from tblHotels order by HotelName";

    using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, new SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST3)))
    {
        cmdSQL.Connection.Open();

        GridView1.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}


protected void cmdSEL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender;
    int rowIX = btn.Attributes.Item["RowID"];

    GridViewRow gRow = GridView1.Rows[rowIX];

    Session("RowData") = gRow;

    Response.Redirect("MyForm2.aspx");
}
```

Now, on web page 2, we have this:

```
       <h2>Hotel information you picked</h2>
        <br />

        <asp:TextBox ID="txtHotel" runat="server" Height="26px" Width="299px" Font-Size="X-Large"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server" Height="26px" Width="299px" Font-Size="X-Large"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
```

And the results look like this:

[image]

And the code was this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
if (IsPostBack == false)
{
    GridViewRow gRow = Session("RowData");


    txtHotel.Text = gRow.Cells[0].Text;
    txtCity.Text = gRow.Cells[1].Text;
}
}
```

In fact, in most cases, I would probably pass the PKID, and have the other page execute a query against the database - this would thus allow you to have any page or any code jump to the 2nd page, and you would not have to pass say JUST a gridview row data row, but only a PK id, and that 2n page could and would load/pull the data from the database.

In other words, while I did pass a WHOLE row of data? I would pass the PK of the product id table, and in the 2nd web page, I would pull that row of data based on PK.

That way, you only pass that one product id. Now in above, I passed RowID. However, I think in real world practice, I would pass the product ID (if exposed). I could also pass the PK ID of that database row (this is best option). However, as general rule I would NOT put or allow the PK ID to appear in the markup.

but, if you pass some kind of PK or product ID? Then you can pull the database row, and get values that way.

eg:

```
public void GetData()
{
using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from tblHotels WHERE ID = @ID", new SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST3)))
{
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session("PKID");

    cmdSQL.Connection.Open();

    DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
    rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader);

    DataRow MyRow = rstData.Rows(0);

    txtHotel.Text = MyRow("HotelName");
    txtCity.Text = MyRow("City");
    etc. etc. etc. etc.
}
}
```

So, pass the PK id, and then on the landing page, you can pull/set all the data you want by pulling the row again from teh database.

I also VERY ,but VERY VERY VERY much recommend that if you use session() to pass the PK row value, the FIRST thing you do is transfer the session() value to viewstate, or a hidden field - you want to persist the value, and NOT use session() for this ANY longer then the page load. The reason is simple - session() is GLOBAL to the one logged on user (or user). So, if they launch two pages (the 2nd page), then both could wind up operating on the same PK row id - so hidden field, hidden textbox or better yet, is on first page load transer the session(PKID) value to viewstate. That way you can have more then one copy of the browser open, and your applciation will not come crashing down like a house of cards - since mutliple pages launch would be assuming the session(PKID) value, but it would be the SAME for the multiple copies of the browser open.

If you don't do this, then if a user opens a page to buy a house, and you open another browser tab to a different house? Well when they click on buy house - they will purchase the WRONG house if you use session(PKID) for this

so session is really nice - no client side values exposed. No parameters, or anything need be shown or display or stored client side. But just keep in mind that session() while server based - it is per user and NOT per web page.
That's why I suggest you quick as possible get/grab the "ID" and then transfer it over to viewstate or something local to the web page. So get/grab ANY session values that are scoped (or need to be) to the ONE page. So things like a logon id - it don't matter. But PK values etc - they often are in the context of the one page, and session() is global to the one user.

Comment: Тhank you for taking the time to resolve my issue.

Comment: I actually wanted to make it work somehow without connecting to my database. So I fixed the problem with putting a label with the Text that needs to be passed to the TextBox Product Name and a Button that redirects to the WebForm2. So when you get there a request query string takes the value and inserts it into the TextBox. However, thank you again.

Comment: Basic concept was to use session() to pass the values. The fact of a database being involved or not is a 100% different issue. The simple matter is the user does something, selects a combo box, or whatever. You use session() and pass the values to the 2nd page. So this is little to do with using a database - a database was used just for example here. Passing information in session() was the valuable concept here. You can use parameters in the URL - and user can change and mess with those parameters. Sometimes parms in URL is ok, sometimes you don't want users changing the URL - it depends.